# How to put ClientFooterTemplate value from DB instead of sum

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Please understand that I am using Google Translator because I am not fluent in English.

I want to put a certain value in the GRID's ClientFooterTemplate, not the sum.

It is a column name that has nothing to do with the column value of the position to be output and does not exist in the grid column.

I would like to put it as a value that is received from db.

If there is more than one query result value in the OnDataBound event, it is accessed with dataitem and the corresponding value is put into the hidden textbox.

Then, we tried to input the following output.
(I don't know how to use clientFooterTemplate, so I wrote a JavaScript function.)

Attach controller READ & GRID by request.
I use RAZOR expressions in other parts, but I do not use them in the parts I want to create.

```
.ClientFooterTemplate("#: kendo.toString(fn_GetCnt(), '\\#\\#,\\#') #")

function fn_GetCnt () {
    return $ ("# ALO_03_CNT"). val ();
}

 public ActionResult ALO_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, string GUBUN, string ALO_ID, string ALO_01, string ALO_02ST, string ALO_02ED, string CAR_04, string RUT_04, int ALO_03, int ALO_04, string ALO_10, string RUT_04G, string CAR_05, string RUT_14, string ALO_05, string TMP2)
    {           
        testQuery Query = new testQuery();
        JsonResult returnJsonResult = new JsonResult();

        ALO_02ST = ALO_02ST.Replace("-", "");
        ALO_02ED = ALO_02ED.Replace("-", "");
        List<AloModels> list = Query.SP_ALO_SELECT(GUBUN, ALO_ID, ALO_01, ALO_02ST, ALO_02ED, CAR_04, RUT_04, ALO_03, ALO_04, ALO_10, RUT_04G, CAR_05, RUT_14, ALO_05, TMP2);

returnJsonResult = Json(list.ToDataSourceResult(request), 
JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
returnJsonResult.MaxJsonLength = 2147483647;

        return returnJsonResult;
    }


  @( Html.Kendo().Grid<BUSCB.Models.AloModels>()
        .Name("grid")
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .ServerOperation(true)
            .PageSize(20)
            .Read(read => read.Action("ALO_Read", "ANB").Data("readParam"))
            .Events(events => events
                .RequestEnd("onRequestEnd")
                .RequestStart("onRequestStart")
            )
        .Aggregates(aggregates =>
        {
            aggregates.Add(p => p.ALO_05).Sum();
            aggregates.Add(p => p.ALO_06).Sum();
            aggregates.Add(p => p.ALO_07).Sum();
            aggregates.Add(p => p.ALO_08).Sum();
            aggregates.Add(p => p.ALO_09).Sum();
            aggregates.Add(p => p.ALO_05_A).Sum();
            aggregates.Add(p => p.ALO_05_B).Sum();
        })
        )
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
    columns.Bound(o => o)
            .Width(30)
            .HeaderTemplate(@<text><input type='checkbox' id='selectAll' onclick="checkAll(this)" /></text>)
                .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center" })
                .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center" })
                .ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' #= isChecked ? checked='checked':'' # class='chkbx' />");         
        columns.Bound(o => o.CAR_04)
            .Title("Car No.")
            .Width(150)
            .ClientFooterTemplate("#: kendo.toString(fn_GetCnt(), '\\#\\#,\\#') #")
            .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;" })
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:left;white-space:nowrap;" })
            .FooterHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:right;white-space:nowrap;" });        
       })
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 712px;", @class = "page1" })
            .Pageable(pageable => pageable
                .PageSizes(false)
                .Refresh(true)
                .ButtonCount(10)
                )
            .Scrollable()
            .Sortable()
            .Events(events => events
                .Change("OnRowClick")
                .DataBound("onDataBound")
            )               
            .ToolBar(tools => tools.Excel().Text("Excel"))
            .Excel(excel => excel
                .FileName(ViewBag.ExcelName)
                .AllPages(true)
                .Filterable(true)
                .ProxyURL(Url.Action("Excel_Export_Save", "AdminRegister")))
            .Reorderable(r => r.Columns(true))
            .Resizable(r => r.Columns(true))
            .Selectable()
    )
```

Although it worked as intended,
The problem was timing.

Rather than drawing the alo_03_cnt value that was received, it draws the grid before onDataBound is done.

(That is, if you search again, the value of alo_03_cnt will appear correctly in the footer.)

How do you put a value before drawing a grid?

Comment: Can you show the rest of the Razor code that configures the grid and the controller code ?

Comment: I tried to use Viewdata in the controller part to perform grid.read, but I was not able to get a value whether the value disappears after reading the grid. After that, I did not do any work on the controller side.

On the controller that will perform the Grid Read,
The list that results from the query has a CNT entry and is bound to the grid
It does not output this as a table.

I failed to directly represent this bound value, and I wanted to output this value to a hidden variable. Is the wrong approach?